# R: How to turn variable name to string

Tags: r, string

I want to turn object1 into a string called "object1"

```
object1 = c(1 ,2 ,3)
object2 = c(3 ,2 ,1)

my_list = list(object1,object2)

for(var in my_list){
  cat(toString(var),"\n")
}
```

this returns

```
1, 2, 3 
3, 2, 1
```

I want it to return

```
"object1"
"object2"
```

Comment: Are you trying to access variable names in your environment or jus list names - what is your goal?

Comment: @GWD my object1 is a time series object and i am attempting to plot several graphs and want to retrieve the name of the object to use for the title

Comment: Then I guess looping through a named list and using that list name "variable" in your plot or `?deparsing` -  I see that @MichaelChirico just elaborated in detail :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to imitate the default plotting behavior:

```
my_x_var = 1:10
my_y_var = 10:1

plot(my_x_var, my_y_var)
```

[image: sample plot]

The way that's done is with `deparse1(substitute(.))`:

```
deparse1(substitute(my_x_var))
# [1] "my_x_var"
```

NB: `deparse1` is new to R 4.0.0. On older versions, you'll in general need to do `paste(deparse(substitute(my_x_var)), collapse = ' ')` -- but this only matters if the argument in `substitute(.)` gets huge (lots of characters). In simple use cases, just `deparse(.)` would suffice.

Comment: Best thing in R 4.0.0 (after reference counting)! I was too lazy to enclose `deparse` with `paste` every single time, but it always gave me sleepless nights.

Answer (score 3):

There is no information of  `"object1"` and `"object2"` in `my_list`.

You need to name them like this :

```
my_list = list(object1 = object1,object2 = object2)
```

Or using `tibble`'s `lst`

```
my_list <- tibble::lst(object1, object2)
```

so that you can access names using

```
names(my_list)
#[1] "object1" "object2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the application stated by the original poster (OP) for the functionality they are after, it's clear that the [answer by MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61851743/6118609) is the right solution.

For potential other applications where we need to ***know the names of the arguments passed during the creation of an object*** (e.g. `"object1"` and `"object2"` in the call to `list(object1, object2)` in the OP's example), below I give a solution that allows retrieving those names at a later stage where the created object is used. The solution is based on *storing the argument names as an attribute* of the created object (in this case the list).

To this end I define a function called `create_list()` that receives any number of arguments (defining the elements of the list to create) whose names are stored as part of the attribute `"args"` of the created list (using the `structure()` function).

```
create_list = function(...) {
  # Extract the function arguments
  # - as.list() separates the different parts of the call into function name and arguments
  # - [-1] removes the function name from the list
  params = as.list(match.call())[-1]

  # Create the list and store the argument names in the attribute "args"
  return( structure(list(...),  args=sapply(params, function(x) deparse(x))) )
}
```

Create the list using the function just defined and check the output.

```
object1 = c(1 ,2 ,3)
object2 = c(3 ,2 ,1)
my_list = create_list(object1, object2)
```

whose output is:

```
> my_list
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 1

attr(,"args")
[1] "object1" "object2"
```

As we can see, the names `"object1"` and `"object2"` are part of the `"args"` attribute of the created list. This attribute can be retrieved using the `attr()` function, as follows:

```
> attr(my_list, "args")
[1] "object1" "object2"
```

Therefore, the functionality requested by the OP can be now implemented as follows (complete code):

```
object1 = c(1 ,2 ,3)
object2 = c(3 ,2 ,1)
my_list = create_list(object1, object2)

i = 0
for(var in my_list) {
  i = i + 1
  cat( attr(my_list, "args")[i], "\n")
}
```

whose output is:

```
object1 
object2
```

**BONUS: EXTENSION TO ANY FUNCTION CALL**

The `create_list()` function defined above can be extended to have the capability of calling *any* function, not only `list()`. This is done by extending the function to accept a new argument containing the function to call (e.g. `list()`, `data.frame()`, etc.). I call the extended function `create_object()` and define it as follows:

```
# Function that runs a function call and returns an object containing the output
# of the call, which includes in attribute "args" the name of the arguments passed to the function.
# The function to call should be the first argument, followed by any potential argument
# to pass to that function.
create_object = function(...) {
  # Extract the function arguments
  # - as.list() separates the different parts of the call into function name and arguments
  # - [-1] removes the function name from the list
  params = as.list(match.call())[-1]
  fun_to_call = params[[1]]
  args = params[-1]
  return( structure(do.call(deparse(fun_to_call), args),
                    args=sapply(args, function(x) deparse(x))) )
}
```

We now call this function to create a list and a data frame, respectively:

```
my_list = create_object(list, object1, object2)
my_df = create_object(data.frame, object1, object2)
```

whose values are:

```
> my_list2
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 1

attr(,"args")
[1] "object1" "object2"

> my_df
  object1 object2
1       1       3
2       2       2
3       3       1
```

The attributes of the data frame are not shown by default when printing, but they can be retrieved with `attributes()`:

```
> attributes(my_df)
$names
[1] "object1" "object2"

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3

$args
[1] "object1" "object2"
```

Clearly, the `"args"` attribute is expected to not already exist in created object, otherwise its value is overwritten.

Finally, note that we can also pass a function that does not create an object, such as `print()` or `ls()`.

```
> create_object(print, object1, object2)
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"args")
[1] "object1" "object2"
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `lst` from `dplyr`

```
dplyr::lst(object1, object2)
```